# Emacs init.el and Elisp and equivalent of common lisp every-p function

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am working on my init.el and would like to setup so that it checks if my defined packages are installed and if not then refresh package contents and install them.

I can automate the install fine, but I only want to refresh the package list if there are packages not installed.

I came up with something that works with common lisp but seems as if elisp does not have every-p which is the simplest method.

```
(defparameter *my-packages* '(evil evil-leader helm))
(defparmeter *installed-pkgs* '())

;fake package-installed-p
(defun package-installed-p(pkg)
  (member pkg *installed-pkgs*))

;fake package-install
(defun package-install(pkg)
  (format t "Installing package: ~a~%" pkg))

(defun check-installed-p()
  (every #'package-installed-p *my-packages*))

(defun mytest()
  (unless (check-installed-p)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (dolist (pkg *my-packages*)
       (unless (package-installed-p pkg)
          (package-install pkg)))))
```

The other method I came up with was the following using return-from but it seems this is not part of elisp. With some searching it looks like I could emulate this with catch and throw.

```
(defun check-installed-p()
    (dolist (pkg *my-packages*)
       (unless (package-installed-p(pkg)
          (return-from check-installed-p NIL)))
    (return-from check-installed-p T))
```

What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT #1**
Using cl-lib and cl-extra

```
(require 'package)
(require 'cl-lib)
(require 'cl-extra)

(push '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") package-archives )

(package-initialize)

(defconst *my-packages* '(evil evil-leader helm))

(defun my-package-check()
  (unless (cl-every #'package-installed-p *my-packages)
    (package-refresh-contents)
    (dolist (pkg *my-packages*)
      (unless (package-installed-p pkg)
        (package-install pkg)))))

(my-package-check)

(require 'evil)
(require 'evil-leader)
(require 'helm-config)
```

**EDIT #2**

To do without require common lisp libraries, replace cl-every with my-every below followint Drew's suggested answer.

Thanks for help!

```
(defun my-every (pred list)
  (while (and list (funcall pred (car list)))
    (setq list (cdr list)))
  (null list))
```

Comment: After more searching, I did find an every-p form in the library cl-extra.el.  If anyone knows how to accomplish this without having to pull in all the extra common lisp libraries I would like a pure elisp solution if you have one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus):

```el
(defun bmkp-every (predicate list)
  "Return t if PREDICATE is true for all elements of LIST; else nil."
  (while (and list  (funcall predicate (car list)))  (setq list  (cdr list)))
  (null list))
```

Comment: Thanks! I would never had thought of doing it this way. So if I understand the while loop:  we loop over list while list is not equal to nil and the result of the predicate function is non nil. Then in body we pop the head of list of and reloop.  So I understand the loop. But how we return T or NIL to caller is unclear. (null list) ?

Comment: Yes. `C-h f null` tells you that `null` returns `t` if the arg is `nil`. (It should also tell you, as does the Elisp manual, node [List-related Predicates](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List_002drelated-Predicates.html), that it returns `nil` of the arg is not `nil`. (I've just filed Emacs [bug #20815](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20815) for the incomplete doc string.) `null` is the same thing as `not`. It generally is used with a list argument, to test for the empty list (`nil`, aka `()`), but it is the same Lisp function (predicate) as `not`.

Answer (score 2):

`seq-every-p` comes from [seq.el](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/seq.html) which is available from GNU ELPA and also will become a built-in package from 25.1.

```
(seq-every-p #'package-installed-p '(helm helm-ls-git helm-ag))
=> t
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to this package. Only draw back is since not in emacs yet, will not help with autoloading packages on current vanilla emacs. Definetly will revist when included in 25.1.

Comment: Old Emacs still can use seq.el since it's a GNU ELPA package just like cl-lib.el, though you need install it yourself (`M-x package-install seq`).